# C2100 illegal indirection Comparator and Sets

Tags: c++, set

I'm trying to sort sets by value rather than keys. I keep running into the illegal indirection issue. The error occurs everytime I try to insert through the LRU cache. I assumed the issue had to do with not using pointers so I converted a and b to pointers instead but it didn't work.

```
struct comp {
    bool operator ()(const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
typedef set<pair<int, int>, comp> S;

struct LRUCache {
    S cache;
    typedef S::iterator it;
    int cap;

    LRUCache(int capacity) {
        cap = capacity;
    }

    int get(int key) {

    }

    void setC(int key, int value) {
        cache.insert(key, value);
    }

    void initialize() {
        vector<int> temp{ 5,20,35,20,83,17,5,1,0,239,242,42 };
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            setC(i, temp[i]);

        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    LRUCache test(5);
    test.initialize();
    test.setC(1, 5);
    test.setC(12, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the complete error?  You'll probably want to work on the example too because this compiles just fine.  http://ideone.com/GjT4aD

Comment: Sorry. I got the same error in my IDE with just that portion so I assumed it was just that block of code.

Comment: `cache.insert(make_pair(key, value));` or `cache.insert({key, value});` are likely what you want.

Comment: Also, I do not recommend using single letter names like `S` to define your types.  That conveys no information whatsoever to someone reading your code.  Instead, call it `IntSet` or something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `std::set` consists of `std::pair<int, int>`, and you're not inserting that type into your set with this line:

```
cache.insert(key, value);
```

This calls the `set::insert` function that takes two parameters, and the compiler is trying to match the two `int` values you're passing with [one of the overloads here that takes two parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Instead what you want to do is call `set::insert` with a single parameter, namely the `std::pair<int, int>`.

Change the above line to this:

```
cache.insert({key, value});
```

or

```
cache.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/8IWggF)

---

You could also have seen the issue more clearly if you used `using` or `typedef` for the `std::pair`.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> IntPair;
typedef std::set<IntPair, comp> PairSet;
//...
PairSet cache;
//...
cache.insert(IntPair(key, value));
```

You know that you want to insert `IntPair`'s into the set, thus the code above would have compiled with no issue.